# sending Sha256 hash as a URL param as signature for Rails request data

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I've noticed that when i send a url like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/register/register_user/?sig=zaQ/876CwJMEEmrJqAOYHyEKBXy2s03NDmk+3FsXPr4=
```

what comes through when I use it to compare to the expected result using params[:sig] in the controller is this:

```
zaQ/876CwJMEEmrJqAOYHyEKBXy2s03NDmk 3FsXPr4=
```

For some reason the '+' sign that was in the url at the 9th character from the end of the string has been converted to a space.

Not sure why that happens, whether it only happens with + signs or what.

The result returned by Digest::SHA256.base64digest(data) has this plus sign so my validation of the signature is failing.

What's the best way to fix this?  Will it suffice in the general case just to convert '+' signs into spaces before the comparison or is the re some less ugly way to address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to url encode it. Either do a search and replace for + with %2B or force the encoding using open-uri.

```
require 'cgi'
sig = "zaQ/876CwJMEEmrJqAOYHyEKBXy2s03NDmk+3FsXPr4="
puts CGI.escape(sig)
```

Tested it this time.

```
irb(main):008:0> require 'cgi'
=> true
irb(main):009:0> CGI.escape('zaQ/876CwJMEEmrJqAOYHyEKBXy2s03NDmk+3FsXPr4=')
=> "zaQ%2F876CwJMEEmrJqAOYHyEKBXy2s03NDmk%2B3FsXPr4%3D"
irb(main):010:0>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to do anything.  The output of the puts above  zaQ/876CwJMEEmrJqAOYHyEKBXy2s03NDmk+3FsXPr4=

Comment: Is the plus sign the only character that might appear in the calculated hash?  Or are there others that might come up which need translating somehow?

Comment: The equal sign will get you also

Comment: looks like CGI.escape does a better job than open-uri for this.